# Parameter 'param_name' not found in collection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, parameters

This is my first attempt at using ADO.NET for MySQL, and I have no idea what's going on. I keep getting the error `Parameter '_name' not found in collection` on the first parameter I try to define.

I have tried reordering, but no matter which way I put it, MySQL always catches up of the first line.

```
mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MajorEquipment.EquipmentNumber, MajorEquipment.EquipmentType, PlantAreaCodes.AreaCode " +
  "FROM MajorEquipment e INNER JOIN PlantAreaCodes a " +
  "ON e.PACId = a.PACId WHERE " +
  "(@EquipmentType IS NULL OR e.EquipmentType = @EquipmentType) " +
  "AND (@EquipmentNumber IS NULL OR e.EquipmentNumber = @EquipmentNumber) " +
  "AND (@AreaCode IS NULL OR a.AreaCode = @AreaCode)";

// The First line shows the error. I have tried @EquipmentType, 
// @EquipmentNumber, and @AreaCode in the first line.

mySqlCommand.Parameters["@EquipmentType"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.EquipmentType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.EquipmentType);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@EquipmentNumber"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.EquipmentNumber) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.EquipmentNumber);
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@AreaCode"].Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.Location) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.Location);

mySqlReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The first parameter *shows* the error, but I'm starting to believe that it may be something to do with the Command string.

I have also tried replacing `e` and `a` with `MajorEquipment` and `AreaCode` respectively.

**Why is this happening?**

Here are my Tables for reference:

```
+----------------+    +-----------------+
| PlantAreaCodes |    | MajorEquipment  |
|----------------|    |-----------------|
| PACId (PKEY)   |    | MEId (PKEY)     |
| AreaCode       |    | EquipmentType   |
| AreaName       |    | PACId (FKEY)    |
| Comments       |    | EquipmentNumber |
+----------------+    +-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parameters to the collection before settings their values or use the shortcut
AddWithValue

```
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EquipmentType", (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.EquipmentType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.EquipmentType));
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EquipmentNumber", (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.EquipmentNumber) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.EquipmentNumber));
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MeModel.Location) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MeModel.Location));
```

Comment: this makes sense. I always seem to miss the obvious stuff and end up overthinking the problem haha. -_-'